# Why PATINDEX function returns 1 without finding anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the code:

```
Select PATINDEX('%[a-z]%','FIRSTNAME')
```

and, the result is 1. I cannot understand.
[image]

Comment: What do you expect the result to be if not 1?

Comment: wht are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Because I am trying to find the lower case letter in FIRSTNAME string, so I think it should return 0 instead of 1.

Comment: That most default installs of SQL Server end up with a case-insensitive default collation is something you ought to learn very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you will need `COLLATE` them as follow

```
SELECT patindex('%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%','FIRSTNAME' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
```